# Programmatically created NSView does not appear when added to parent view

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsview

I have the following code in my ViewController

```
@IBAction func showView(sender: AnyObject) {
    show()
}

func show() {

    let viewHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height
    let viewWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let posX: CGFloat = self.view.frame.origin.x
    let posY: CGFloat = self.view.frame.origin.y
    let viewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(posX, posY, viewWidth, viewHeight)

    let view: NSView = NSView(frame: viewFrame)
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor

    self.view.addSubview(view)

}
```

I don't understand why upon clicking the `showView` button the NSView does not appear? As a sanity check I tried moving the call (and later on the code) to the `viewDidLoad` method, again to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Solve it yourself. You have a debugger. Debug! Are the height, width, x, and y values turning out the way you expect? Does the view actually have a layer, or is your red color failing (so that you end up with a clear view you can't see)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never said

```
view.wantsLayer = true
```

So your view has no layer, and applying a background color to the layer has no effect because (as I just said) your view has no layer. So the view is there but you can't *see* it; it is transparent, like the Invisible Man.

Comment: You were completely right to say that I should debug for myself. I did that for width / height and position... Never did it for the CALayer. Now I know. Thank you for the prompt reply!

Comment: The joy of assigning into a optionally unwrapped Optional (`view.layer?`) is that you don't crash. The downside is that you don't know whether anything happened! :) There are ways of finding out, but we must make no assumptions...

Comment: I completely get it! I was foolishly assuming that an NSView uses a CALayer by default! Thank you for your input once again. Next time something like this happens I'll go through the documentation and debug appropriately.