# Why this swift code does not show up line and the animation?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

Why is the `MyViewController` does not get's shown in the window although the it's stated in the `contentViewController: MyViewController()` ?

I'm not on storyboard or XIB and I don't wanna use a nib file.

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create a new window
        window = NSWindow(contentViewController: MyViewController())
        // Make the window visible
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

    
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func loadView() {
        let view = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
        self.view = view
        
        // Create a shape layer for the rectangle
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(value: 6), NSNumber(value: 4)]
        
        // Create a path for the rectangle
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addRect(NSRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        shapeLayer.path = path
        
        // Create an animation for the dashed line
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = shapeLayer.lineDashPattern?.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.intValue }
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "lineDashPhase")
        
        // Add the shape layer to the view hierarchy
        view.layer?.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically created NSView does not appear when added to parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708777/programmatically-created-nsview-does-not-appear-when-added-to-parent-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not on storyboard or XIB and I don't wanna use a nib file.

If you want to use the programmatic approach then you don't need the controllers for a basic window as shown in the demo below.  To run the following in Xcode first create a Swift project, add a 'main.swift' file, and then delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate file.  Copy/paste this code into the 'main' file and run.  I added a green background to your view so that you could see its bounds.  You need to set .wantsLayer to true and then add the view as a subview to the window.contentView.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window:NSWindow!
    var view: NSView!
    
    func buildMenu() {
        let mainMenu = NSMenu()
        NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
        // **** App menu **** //
        let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
        let appMenu = NSMenu()
        appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
        appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")
    }
    
    func buildWnd() {
        
        let _wndW : CGFloat = 400
        let _wndH : CGFloat = 400
        
        window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
        window.center()
        window.title = "Swift Test Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
        // **** CAShapeLayer with Animation **** //
        view = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
        window.contentView!.addSubview (view)
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
        
        // Create a shape layer for the rectangle
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(value: 6), NSNumber(value: 4)]
        
        // Create a path for the rectangle
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addRect(NSRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        shapeLayer.path = path
        
        // Create an animation for the dashed line
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = shapeLayer.lineDashPattern?.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.intValue }
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "lineDashPhase")
        
        // Add the shape layer to the view hierarchy
        view.layer?.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        // **** Quit btn **** //
        let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
        quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
        quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
        quitBtn.title = "Q"
        quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
        window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
    }
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        buildMenu()
        buildWnd()
    }
    
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let app = NSApplication.shared
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: in xcode I don't have a main.swift file, only the appdelegate file. so, I don't know where to place the last 6 lines of code. I created the project with xCode, XIB, Swift, or did I do something wrong.

Comment: update: I just deleted the last 6 lines, which you asked to put into main.swift, and it works fine. Is it a must to place the last 6 lines? does it serve any other purpose than running the appdelegate?.

Comment: You have to create 'main.swift' by using the File menu of Xcode, ie File/New/File and choose Swift File type.  Hit 'Next' and enter 'main.swift' as name of file then hit Create button.  Should look like edited answer above.  I delete the AppDelegate file because Xcode won't allow two AppDelegates.  If you wanted to you could go ahead and use the pre-supplied AppDelegate which is apparently what you did.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your problem is at least in part the same as in the answer Willeke linked (From Matt)

> The problem is that you never said
>
> `view.wantsLayer = true`
>
> So your view has no layer, and applying a background color to the
> layer has no effect because (as I just said) your view has no layer.
> So the view is there but you can't see it; it is transparent, like the
> Invisible Man.

Try adding the line `view.wantsLayer = true` after you create your view.

Comment: Please don't copy answers. Flag the question as duplicate instead.